# Add raster values under points to table

Tags: arcgis-desktop, raster, point, attribute-table

I have some points overlayed on top of a raster.  Is there a tool in ArcGIS Desktop to add the values of the raster that the points fall on top of into the point attribute table?
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the "Extract Values to Points" tools under ArcToolbox -> Spatial Analyst Tools -> Extraction.

Comment: yes but then how do I relate the 2 to get them in the same table?

Comment: Both attribute tables of your point file and new file you'll get using "extract values to points" tool will have a common attribute field. Based on this field you can use "Join Field" tool under Arc Toolbox -> Data Management Tools -> Joins.

Comment: Ahhh...there's even an option to append the raster values to the point table in the extract values to points tool.  TYVM!!